# Nodejs is showing error EPERM, how can i fix it?

Tags: node.js

```html
PS C:\New folder> npm install -g yo generator-code
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\generator-code
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\generator-code'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\generator-code'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\generator-code'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Forever\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-25T04_10_40_095Z-debug.log
```

when I tried to install npm install -g yo generator-code its showing this error . i have run it three times 2 on windows 1 on Linux but everytime its showing this error how can i fix it

Comment: what is your npm version?

Comment: The error *seems* clear enough–it's telling you that you do not have permission to do what the NPM command wants to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a permission issue

i would recommned `you configure npm to not require sudo/Admin permission to install global packages`.

for now just `downgrade your npm version` or run your cmd with 'Admin privileges'.

if these steps doesn't help

then run this `npm cache clean --force` and then try reinstalling your package.

Comment: thank you so much i have been trying to solve it for 2 days  and this is my first question on stackoverflow i have tried you suggestions 1 by one and run it again and its working now thank you 10000.. times o(*°▽°*)o