# node.js `Error:Cannot find module 'CoreDb'` / npm EPERM Error

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install, permission-denied, sailfish-os

I am trying to execute [the **jolla-sms-exporter** program by vostoksystems from GitHub](https://github.com/vostoksystem/jolla-sms-exporter) to export my sms from a Sailfish OS device.
It requires `node.js` and `npm` modules (`yargs`).

I managed to copy the files from the project page (`main.js` and `package.json`) in the corresponding folder on my sd card and to `ssh` to that folder from my terminal. I also installed node.js (v12.17.0) using the Storeman-package manager and then installed npm (version 6.14.4) with some brute force from the command line:

```
root$ npm install --force
```

but still got errors when doing so saying `gyp WARN EACCES current user 'nemo' does not have permission...`

Finally, if I try to execute

```
node main.js
```

I receive the error code

```
Error: Cannot find module './libs/CoreDb'
```

When I try updating / installing further npm modules, i.e. `npm install CoreDb` I get an error saying upper case letters are not permitted, when using lower case, it says it can't be found.
The module is called in `main.js` by

```
const CoreDb = require('./libs/CoreDb')
```

Can anyone give me a hint what went wrong here?

I have seen and tried the following solutions:

[Node js Error: Cannot find module './lib/socket.io'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323982/error-cannot-find-module-lib-cli)

[Node.js Error: Cannot find module express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162308/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-express)

[How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

[Nodejs is showing error EPERM, how can i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64998444/nodejs-is-showing-error-eperm-how-can-i-fix-it)

Sorry for being a total newb on anything java, node, etc. I would really appreciate any help on that!

Thanks and best,
Nik